# How to make real use of Postman's Authorization?

Tags: node.js, api, postman

I know how the authorization in postman works. But I don't know how to use it practically.
For example I have finished building my api for logging in users and then later on authenticate them using the generated token. In postman I take the token and make it available for all the paths that are using the middleware 'auth'. My question is that how can I make use of it out of the postman.

Comment: you mean in your code?

Comment: define 'real use'?

Comment: @mehta-rohan 
No, not in my code.
How to implement it in a real world application. Out of the the postman's environment.

When I create a user the user is gonna have a token will be logged in automatically, the token will be stored in a postman variable and when I want to authenticate the user I get the token from the postman. What should I do when there is no postman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have something like a JWT being returned from your login/register actions, in order to 'Use it' in your app one of the common solutions is to append it to an Authorization header in the API call.

Again, if talking about a JWT, and using js `fetch` it should look like this

```
fetch("http://myapp.com/myEndpoint",
 {
   method: "GET",
   headers: {
       "Content-Type": "application/json",
       Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
   },
 }
)
```

Comment: Thank you @Pablo!